# Easily provide a docker based solution to a lambda user

Tags: docker

I am considering building a solution running on a docker. I assume the end user will run this docker image but won't ever understand the terminal. How can one pack this image into a simple application ? Should I simply build an app around a shell script or is there a better option dedicated to docker ?
(I target OS X for now)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into how the [boot2docker for OS X installer](https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer) is packaged and use that as a starting point. Unfortunately there's no way to natively run docker on Mac OS X so you'll have to have to install virtualization software like boot2docker does.

Also, [Kitematic](https://github.com/kitematic/kitematic) was recently acquired by docker and has a terminal-less interface to docker.

Comment: I tried both of them but they are still too complex for a simple user. I probably will have to consider building my own gui on top of a smart script.